# About iteration count for recursive function

Tags: r, recursion

I am trying to write out the bisection function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) as asked in the HW, and I want to count the iteration number.

Here's the code:

```
itera = 0
bisect <- function(f, lower, upper, tol)
{
  mid <- (lower + upper)/2
  if(abs(f(mid)) < tol){
    output <- list(root = mid, f.root = f(mid), iter = itera, estim.prec = abs(f(mid)))
    return(output)
  }
  else{
    itera = itera + 1
    if(f(mid) * f(lower) < 0){
      
      bisect(f, lower, mid, tol)
    }
    else{
      
      bisect(f, mid, upper, tol)
    }
  }
}
f <- function(x) {x^3 - 2*x - 1}
bisect(f,1,2,10^(-6))
```

My test function is `x^3 - 2*x - 1`, and the output:

[image]

shows the iteration number is 0, I don't know how can I debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifications to `itera` inside a function are done in the function's environment, not in the global environment.

You could pass `itera` as parameter to the function so that each recursive call increments its value:

```
bisect <- function(f, lower, upper, tol, itera=1)
{
  mid <- (lower + upper)/2
  if(abs(f(mid)) < tol){
    output <- list(root = mid, f.root = f(mid), iter = itera, estim.prec = abs(f(mid)))
    return(output)
  }
  else{
    itera = itera + 1
    if(f(mid) * f(lower) < 0){
      
      bisect(f, lower, mid, tol,itera)
    }
    else{
      
      bisect(f, mid, upper, tol,itera)
    }
  }
}
f <- function(x) {x^3 - 2*x - 1}
bisect(f,1,2,10^(-6))

$root
[1] 1.618034

$f.root
[1] -6.01767e-07

$iter
[1] 21

$estim.prec
[1] 6.01767e-07
```

Another option is to modify `itera` value in calling environment using `<<-` operator :

```
itera <- 1
bisect <- function(f, lower, upper, tol)
{
  mid <- (lower + upper)/2
  if(abs(f(mid)) < tol){
    output <- list(root = mid, f.root = f(mid), iter = itera, estim.prec = abs(f(mid)))
    return(output)
  }
  else{
    itera <<- itera + 1
    if(f(mid) * f(lower) < 0){
      
      bisect(f, lower, mid, tol)
    }
    else{
      
      bisect(f, mid, upper, tol)
    }
  }
}

$root
[1] 1.618034

$f.root
[1] -6.01767e-07

$iter
[1] 21

$estim.prec
[1] 6.01767e-07


f <- function(x) {x^3 - 2*x - 1}
bisect(f,1,2,10^(-6))
```